# Conjecture over this series, and its generalisation

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, conjectures

**PART I**

The following series, according to W. Mathematica, does converge to

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-k}}{k^k \sqrt{k}} = 0.3929049383779132(...)$$

The previous result can be written in terms of elementary numbers plus the Euler constant, as follows:

$$0.3929049383779132 \approx \frac{-92-95 e+86 e^2}{2 \left(130-4 e+33 e^2\right)}$$

**Question** Is that conjecture true? Probably it's a lack of mine but I cannot manage to make W. Mathematica to spit out more digits of the previous number.

**PART II**

The previous series was actually a special case for $x = 1$ of the more general series:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k e^{-k}}{k^k \sqrt{kx}}$$

**Question**: Is there a close form for this?

I tried with many values of $x$ and the series always gets a numerical result, but Mathematical cannot give me a close form.

I am not assuming a priori it does exist, but many times people found out close forms whereas software could not.

Comment: My Mathematica says by numerical experiments that the first conjecture is not true. The sum is approx. 0.392904938377913246088528599518, where the fraction its approx. 0.392904938377913220060510847383.

Comment: @sranthrop That is already good. One question out!

Comment: May I ask how you found the fraction in Part I?

Comment: Introducing $t=x/e$ your question can be reduced to that one about the closed form for $\sum (t/k)^k/\sqrt{k}$. Observe also that your last sum is ill-defined for $k=0$.

Comment: @user Thank you for the comment! Also I fixed the typo, I clearly meant from $k = 1$!

Comment: @Von Did you follow some procedure or just randomly checked to get this approximate value

Comment: With $\sqrt{k}$ in there, it seems unlikely that there is a closed form.

Comment: @GEdgar Why do you think that? If we had just $e^{-k}/\sqrt{k}$ the sum would end up in a Polylog function. Just to say, but I admit that this is a simpler series.

Comment: @Von did you try this? It is a pure approximation but in closed form. Using Stirlings formule for $n!$ we get:

$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k e^{-k}}{k^k \sqrt{{k}{x}}}$$\approx$$\sqrt\frac{{2\pi}}{x}$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{({xe^{-2}})^{k}}{k!}$=$\sqrt\frac{{2\pi}}{x}$$\big(e^{xe^{-2}}-1\big)$ 

At $x=1$ its value is about $0.363262....$

Comment: @JV.Stalker Nice one! maybe with more terms from Stirling series it will acquire more precision. I'll give it a try, thank you! (Ps you should add it as an answer!)

Comment: @Von no more terms, $n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\big(\frac{n}{e}\big)^n$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @JV.Stalker This is just the first order approximation, there are other terms in Stirling series!

Comment: @Von yes, but then probably we have problem with the closed form later I will check it. Thankx and regards.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pure approximation but in closed form.

Using Stirlings formule for $n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\big(\frac{n}{e}\big)^n$ we get:

$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{x^k e^{-k}}{k^k \sqrt{{k}{x}}}$$\approx$$\sqrt\frac{{2\pi}}{x}$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{({xe^{-2}})^{k}}{k!}$=$\sqrt\frac{{2\pi}}{x}$$\big(e^{xe^{-2}}-1\big)$

At $x=1$ its value is about $0.363262....$